# AD group users cannot access sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory

I have added some users to a AD security group and I am adding that AD group to my SharePoint 2013 site but when I am trying to login with the ID of AD Group user the site is giving me Access Denied. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has been logged in before, their AD group memberships will be cached (by default for 12 hours) as part of the Claims.

You should therefor allow 12 hours to pass and see if the users gain the access.

Comment: if you need to solve it now, you can add the users to the SharePoint Group that the AD group is part of (if that's how you have it set up), and remove them tomorrow. SharePoint group changes are immediate.

Comment: Good addition for a quick fix

Comment: I want to add the users to the AD group and want to have that AD Group in the Sharepoint group.

Comment: Then my answers should help you understand what is going on

Comment: actually I have a custom page which has a link on it to /_windows/default.aspx  which shows users the windows authentication dialog but if I use the default sign in page for mixed mode the AD group works by that.